# Ubuntu-Lubuntu on a Intel i7-4500, 8GB RAM

Tags: lubuntu

I am switching to a Ubuntu-like OS (from Windows8) and I have been reading around about its derivates. I decided to choose between Lubuntu (for its idea of energy saving and lightweight) and the standard Ubuntu, so here is my question: is it really appreciable the difference of performance on a HP, Intel i7-4500 with 8Gb RAM (and Nvidia video card)?

Thank You!

Comment: you could also try PuppyLinux. Really lightweight base on Trusty. All goodies in damn small package.

Answer (score 1):

I only install Lubuntu if Ubuntu fails.  Most of the time this is on very old hardware or on very small screens or other hand-me-down hardware.

So on your system, I would *definitely*  install Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS.

If you've never seen any: Lubuntu looks like Windows 95 and Ubuntu Looks like Windows 11! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to install Lubuntu. Lubuntu is lightweight but looks modern and it's quick but you can install Lubuntu Desktop alongside Unity in Ubuntu and use both.